# TOPN DAX function is giving all items, Instead of top 3 Employee names

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am creating a report in which there is one table which should shows top 3 Employee Names and there respective sale amounts based on there Sales Amount.

When TOPN is used alone, I get correct output in form of new table. But its without sale Amount. However when TOPN is used along with CALCULATE function, I get all the Employee Names, which is incorrect

DAX query that works well but has only one column:

```
TOPN(3,values(Sale[Employee Name]),CALCULATE(sum(Sale[Total Excluding Tax])))
```

**DAX Measure** which is not filtering the top 3 rows :

```
TopN = CALCULATE(SUM(Sale[Total Excluding Tax]),TOPN(3,values(Sale[Employee Name]),CALCULATE(sum(Sale[Total Excluding Tax]))))
```

Where am I going wrong, please let me know. Screenshot of both the queries is as follows:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your first DAX query is working:

```
TOPN(3,values(Sale[Employee Name]),CALCULATE(sum(Sale[Total Excluding Tax])))
```

How about just creating a simple SUM-measure and adding it as another column, next to the TOPN?

```
Sum sales = SUM(Sale[Total Excluding Tax])
```

It should work, since your TOPN is calculating correctly. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Yes, you got the question right. However if TOPN is used alone it creates a separate table, which I don't want to create unnecessary..Also I want to know why TOPN along with calculate is not working

Comment: Okay, I understand. I've mostly used TOPN in creating calculated tables, so I'm afraid I have no idea how to use Calculate with TOPN. I do have a small workaround in mind, which I've used before. How about filtering the results using RANKX? Like this:

 `Top N 3 Total sales only = IF(RANKX(ALL(Sales);[Sum X of Total sales])>4;[Sum X of Total sales])` This way you can have a table which shows all employees, but sums only the values from the top 3. The SUMX-measure used is just SUMX of your wanted table and column.

Comment: Thanks your RankX method worked..When TopN function is used inside calculate function , it calculates topN numbers but does fillter out the list. RANKX does the job.. Thanks for your time and effort..